# Including a fallback in default shell

Tags: terminal, shell, chsh

I have an account on a network, and my shell is set to `zsh`, but when I log onto a computer that doesn't have `zsh` installed on it, a terminal I launch tries to run `zsh` and fails, so I get an empty terminal. I want to set my shell to something that will fall back to `bash` if `zsh` doesn't exist. I'd want to try something like:

```
zsh || bash
```

but I don't know how the shell I set in `chsh` is parsed, so I'm afraid I'll never be able to log in again if I set it to something wrong. What's the right setting for this?